# Noun or verb modifier in a sentence

Tags: grammar

> He opened his great coat,which he held **bundled up** in his arms.

What does the word **''bundled up''** modify, "held" or "great coat"?

What type of clause is it?

Answer (score 3):

> He held [**his great coat**] [*bundled up*] in his arms.

In the sentence above **bundled up** is a predicative complement and it's object oriented. That means *bundled up* is predicated upon **his great coat**. **his great coat** is *bundled up* in his arms.

So to answer your question, it modifies **great coat**, not **held**.

Now analyze your sentence:

> He opened his great coat, which he held bundled up in his arms.

The part - *which he held bundled up in his arms* - is a relative clause, introduced by the relativizer - *which*.

Here in this sentence there is a gap.

> He opened his great coat, which he held _____ bundled up in his arms.

The antecedent of the gap is the nominal - **great coat**.

Comment: Surely the NP is the antecedent of _which._ What is the purpose of the gap here?

Comment: @P.E.Dant What I mean by *gap* is that some words are missing. That *which* is linked to that gap. Both of them as the same function - *object of "held"*.

Comment: Obviously a gap connotes absent words. Perhaps you are trying to illustrate this: **He held __which__ bundled up in his arms.**

Comment: @P.E.Dant hmmm.

Comment: @P.E.Dant You're right. Man_From_India was trying to illustrate that idea, but writing such a gap as _____ (as opposed to \_which\_) is probably more common. Here is a book that uses the same convention Man_From_India uses: *[A Student's Introduction to English Grammar](https://books.google.comth/books?id=AMAgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA184)* by Rodney Huddleston, Geoffrey K. Pullum.

Comment: @DamkerngT. :) I know. I was trying to hint MFI toward an edit which is, at least to me, easier to express than Huddleston's with the typographic tools at our disposal here.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Hmm... It didn't occur to me you had that thought, but I might've misunderstood your comment. Personally, I think writing *He opened his great coat, which he held \_which\_ bundled up in his arms* looks wrong. Then again, I'm sure you know how most learners are taught to transform *He held SOMETHING bundled up in his arms* into *which he held _____ bundled up in his arms*, though I don't think it's safe to assume that all of our learners know it, so unless the transformation steps are explicitly written, writing a gap as _____ rather than \_which\_ is more appropriate, in my opinion.

Comment: Good point. The method I suggest requires a little exposition. I would point out that turning the clause _which he held bundled up in his arms_ into a declarative sentence will reveal the antecedent of _which._

Comment: I think there are two possible analyses here. Either you perceive "bundled up in his arms" to be explaining **how** he held his greatcoat, in which case it's a manner adjunct modifying "held" **or** you see it as describing the greatcoat, in which case it’s a modifier in NP structure modifying the object "his greatcoat". In the latter analysis, the relative clause is, effectively, "he held [his greatcoat bundled up in his arms]" where the bracketed element is a noun phrase headed by "greatcoat" with "bundled up in his arms" as modifier.

Comment: Incidentally, past-participial clauses like “bundled up in his arms” often occur as post-head modifiers. They are semantically like relative clauses: “his greatcoat which was bundled up in his arms”.